# In depth assessment of SuperMap GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, software-recommendations, supermap-gis

Does anybody have any idea about SuperMap GIS?

- What are its limitations and strengths?
- How does it compare to other GIS (especially ArcGIS)?
- Can a local Government Department rely on it?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to just ask about one specific requirement that you have and may be concerned about, please?  Otherwise, I think your question is too broad and/or too likely to generate opinion-based answers.  From the [help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: I just need two or three points showing the strengths and weaknesses. Anyone who has used the software thoroughly would be able to answer i guess.

Comment: Of the nearly 38,000 questions asked here this is the [first one that mentions SuperMap](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=supermap) so there may be no one here who has used it thoroughly.  To discover whether software is likely to meet your requirements there is no substitute for undertaking a trial of it.  Asking here about specific feature comparisons as you start to use them would fit our focussed Q&A format much better.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. Sorry about the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any GIS can globally compare to ArcGIS. But it all depends on the amount of money you are willing to spend, how/ for what purpose you will be using the GIS and the amount of data to be handled by the GIS.

Comment: Can you give me more details on this? Like functionality?